# Oracle trigger before insert if statement

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, triggers

I've got the following trigger to check if there are available beds in a table called `WARD` before the user tries to input a value, if not then an error will be shown.

```
create or replace 
trigger checkBeds
  before insert or update on INPATIENT_STAY for
    each row
Begin
select BEDSAVAIL from WARD where wardnum=:new.WARDNUM;
if(BEDSAVAIL <=0) then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are no beds available.');
end if;
END;
```

when this is run I get the following error:

> Error(2,42): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.WARDNUM'

`WARD` is linked to `INPATIENT_STAY` by a foreign key in `INPATIENT_STAY` called `WARDNUM`

Here's the structure of the `WARD` table

```
CREATE TABLE WARD 
(
  WARDNUM VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, NAME VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) 
, LOCATION VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, TOTALBEDS NUMBER 
, TELEXTENTION VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, BEDSAVAIL NUMBER 
, CONSTRAINT WARD_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    WARDNUM 
  ));
```

here's the structure of the `INPATIENT_STAY` table

```
CREATE TABLE INPATIENT_STAY 
(
  INPATIENTID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, PATIENTNUMBER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, WADNUM VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, DATEONWAITINGLIST DATE 
, EXPECTEDDURATION VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, EXPECTEDLEAVEDATE DATE 
, DATEPLACEDINWARD DATE 
, REQWARD VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, DATELEFT DATE 
, CONSTRAINT INPATIENT_STAY_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    INPATIENTID 
  )
);
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the value of `BEDSAVAIL` to a local variable and compare with it.

Try like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER checkbeds
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON inpatient_stay 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
     l_bedsavail ward.bedsavail%TYPE;
BEGIN
     SELECT bedsavail 
     INTO   l_bedsavail
     FROM   ward 
     WHERE  wardnum=:NEW.wadnum;
     IF(l_bedsavail <= 0) THEN
          raise_application_error( -20001, 'There are no beds available.'); --to restrict the insetion`.
     END IF;
END;
/
```

**Edited:**

There is a mistake in the column_name in `INPATIENT_STAY`. The name is `WADNUM` instead of `WARDNUM`. Please rename the column name in the table or made changes in the Trigger.

I have updated my answer with column_name `WADNUM`.

```
WHERE  wardnum=:NEW.wadnum;
```

To restrict the insertion or updation on table `INPATIENT_STAT`, you can raise an application error like,

```
raise_application_error( -20001, 'There are no beds available.')
```

Comment: Are you sure the column `WARDNUM` is there in tables `WARD` &  `INPATIENT_STAY`?

Comment: Or please verify that your columns are created without double quotes. Please share your complete create table script for `WARD` AND `INPATIEND_STAY`.

Comment: The trigger compiles ok, but i am still allowed to insert data if the `bedsavail` is 0. how do i prevent this?

Comment: You mean you need to restrict the insertion on table `INPATIENT_STAY` , if `ward.bedsavail <= 0`?

Comment: @Pindo, to restrict the insertion, you can raise an application error instead of `DBMS_OUTPUT`. See the updated answer.